# Erratic behavior just after SWIG C++/Python module loads

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2010, swig, anaconda

I am using SWIG to wrap a C++ extension module for Python. My module compiles and imports successfully. About 50% of the time the Python script that imports it is stable, running without error even when I leave it looping continual tests of the extension module for 10+ hours. However, the other half of the time I get a highly unpredictable exception during the first test or two, about a second after loading the extension module. Out of these bad runs, on occasion Python crashes, but the rest of the time I get a RuntimeError. The error tracebacks often point to lines of code that are pure Python and don't touch the extension module, so has to be some kind of asynchronous issue.

I'll be happy to provide whatever portions of code are appropriate, but I don't want to litter my question with irrelevant details. Please let me know if you'd like to see a particular portion of the code. Here's the SWIG code for exception handling:

```
%exception {
    try {
        $action
    } catch(IndexException &e) {
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_IndexError, const_cast<char*>(e.what()));
    } catch(MemoryException &e) {
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_NullReferenceError, const_cast<char*>(e.what()));
    } catch(Inconsistency &e) {
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_OverflowError, const_cast<char*>(e.what()));
    } catch(std::exception &e) {
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_UnknownError, const_cast<char*>(e.what()));
    } catch(...) {
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "Unknown exception");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's related, but sometimes when I hit Ctrl-C the traceback for the KeyboardInterrupt is displayed but then Python crashes. Other times I'll get a TypeError from SWIG for the self argument to my wrapped code, along with an optional crash of Python. But most of the time, the KeyboardInterrupt works as expected.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Version information:

```
swigwin-3.0.5
Python 3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Sep 24 2014, 18:32:42) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
MS Visual C++ for Python 64-bit
MS Windows 7 SDK v7.0A
```

Build Steps:

```
SWIG Command Line:     C:\MinGW\msys\opt\swigwin-3.0.5\swig.exe -c++ -python -Wall ORM_module.i
Pre-Bulid Step:        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
Compiler Command Line: cl.exe /nologo /MD /EHa /Wp64 -Wall  -O2    /IC:\Users\Aaron\Anaconda3\include /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\include" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\WinSDK\Include" /I"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include" /c ORM_module_wrap.cxx /Foobj\Release\ORM_module_wrap.obj
Linker Command Line:   link.exe /dll /nologo /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Aaron\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\lib\amd64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\WinSDK\Lib\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\x64" /out:bin\Release\_ORM.dll C:\Users\Aaron\Anaconda3\libs\python34.lib obj\Release\error_handling.obj obj\Release\OrderRelation.obj obj\Release\OrderRelationMap.obj obj\Release\ORM_module_wrap.obj  /VERBOSE:LIB /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT -s 
Post-Build Step:       mt.exe -manifest "$(TARGET_OUTPUT_FILE).manifest" -outputresource:"$(TARGET_OUTPUT_FILE)";2
```